# Select the min(ID), number where every number has multiple IDs

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables that contain common ID for every number. 
table1 contains only 1 row with the number for every ID.  Based on this number and the respective ID, I want to find at table2 the minimum ID and display this unique ID for every number (of 1st table).
table2 contains multiple IDs (for number of table1).

My SQL is like:

```
select table1.ID, table1.number 
from table1, table2 
where table2.ID = table1.ID 
and table1.number in (<list of comma separated numbers>);
```

But this returns ALL IDs for every number, so multiple rows for every number with all the IDs that match my condition.

-> I need to just display only the min ID for every number.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your tables and some sample data to illustrate the problem (i.e. DDL and DML statements) and an example of your expected output.

Comment: could you please provide some reference data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your text description, something like:

```
SELECT MIN( t2.ID ) AS min_id,
       t1.number 
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t1
       ON ( t2.ID = t1.ID )
WHERE  t1.number in (<list of comma separated numbers>)
GROUP BY t1.number;
```

However, without some sample data is is difficult to tell.

Comment: MT0: Don't know if I can ask here, but:  Is there any way to also get (select) related data (text) from a table3, where t3.ID=t1.ID=MIN(t2.ID)?  When I try to do so with:  select SELECT MIN( t2.ID ) AS min_id, t1.number, t3.data, I get error that "not a GROUP BY expression" for the t3.  I tried to do with left join table3 on t3.ID=t1.ID ...